# WebRTC H264/VP8

Tags: webrtc, h.264, vp8, janus-gateway

I use Janus-Gateway and I have a problem with choosing codecs between H264 / VP8. When I choose the H264 codec works on IOS but does not work on Chrome 71 (Android) or when I choose VP8 works on Chrome 71 (Android) but it does not work on IOS, is there a way that it works on both normally??

```
v=0
o=- 1548787135566484 1 IN IP4 
s=VideoRoom 5678
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video
a=msid-semantic: WMS janus
a=ice-lite
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111
c=IN IP4 
a=sendonly
a=mid:audio
a=rtcp-mux
a=ice-ufrag:d3jE
a=ice-pwd:JpX8g/jACKyD9331XVlKC9
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 A8:99:87:1B:32:F2:7B:70:51:F9:D8:5C:FF:21:16:86:3D:32:59:8B:89:E4:C1:8A:44:FA:47:1A:1A:18:E2:F4
a=setup:actpass
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=ssrc:3270748517 cname:janusaudio
a=ssrc:3270748517 msid:janus janusa0
a=ssrc:3270748517 mslabel:janus
a=ssrc:3270748517 label:janusa0
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 107
c=IN IP4 
a=sendonly
a=mid:video
a=rtcp-mux
a=ice-ufrag:d3jE
a=ice-pwd:JpX8g/jACKyD9331XVlKC9
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 A8:99:87:1B:32:F2:7B:70:51:F9:D8:5C:FF:21:16:86:3D:32:59:8B:89:E4:C1:8A:44:FA:47:1A:1A:18:E2:F4
a=setup:actpass
a=rtpmap:107 H264/90000
a=fmtp:107 profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1
a=rtcp-fb:107 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack
a=rtcp-fb:107 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:107 goog-remb
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=ssrc:1373947363 cname:janusvideo
a=ssrc:1373947363 msid:janus janusv0
a=ssrc:1373947363 mslabel:janus
a=ssrc:1373947363 label:janusv0
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have some doubts that Chrome 71 (Android) doesn't support H.264 WebRTC.
I don't have any Android devices to try it. So you may see an Android device specific issue. iOS doesn't support VP8 which is against the standard.

As this point in time I'd use H.264.

Let's just assume that you have two clients that don't share a common video format.
You could use Janus as media relay and setup a transcode plugin.
https://github.com/chetanbnaik/janus-gateway-transcoder

This will add additional latency because you have to decode and encode and you'd be in for additional power consumption for the relative compute intensive encodes.

Answer (score 0):

Safari Technology Preview now supports the vp8 codec in WebRTC, so it should be available in the next release.